# azure search query with + returns items with only one of the fields

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-queues

I have an Azure search query with "&search=item1+item2" (I've also tried && and AND, as well as spaces between operator and items) - but the return items always include those with just "item1" and just "item2".  Is there something I am missing?  The items are regular strings, not Unicode or special characters.

Comment: Hi Gina, could you share your index definition, and sample document that you expect to be found, but it is not?

Comment: try `&search=item1%2Bitem2`

Comment: Thanks,  hr-tis - that's what I was missing!